# Wordpress Search Query Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out why this query returns all post types and not just the ones specified. Any help would be helpful.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('insight') 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_posts.post_status != 'private' 
AND wp_posts.post_status != 'future' 
AND wp_posts.post_status != 'trash' 
AND wp_terms.slug LIKE '%great%' 
OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%great%' 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: You're going to need to explain what "not working" means in terms of expected results, and also what you're getting and how that's incorrect.

Comment: It should only be returning posts with post type set to insight wp_posts.post_type IN ('insight') thanks

Comment: It's odd that you're using `IN` with a single case where `=` would be better, and then you have a bunch of contradictory tests on `post_status`. Either that's `post_status NOT IN ('private', 'future', 'trash')` or `post_status = 'publish', but not both. Obviously if a record is set as `'publish'` it's impossible for it to be any of those other values.

Comment: The `1=1` part is also symptomatic of code that should compile a list of clauses in an array and then join with `' AND '` instead of always appending `AND x` on the end of a query string. `1=1` doesn't do much, but it's junk in your query that can be avoided.

Comment: I figured it out. I was missing  curly brackets in my OR statement.  AND (wp_terms.slug LIKE '%great%' OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%great%') LIMIT 0, 10 "

Comment: That's another problem, yeah. Remember, a more minimal query makes those sorts of mistakes stand out better. This is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem probably it's in your `OR`, you should use the `OR` inside parentheses `()`. As you are doing, the query will ignore all your clauses before. Try this:

```
AND ( wp_terms.slug LIKE '%great%' OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%great%' )
```